# "docker run hello-world" with authorization error

Tags: docker

I installed docker successfully on mac.

```
docker -v
Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3.
```

But when I do this:

```
docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp 192.168.65.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I pasted `https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/` in my browser and got this error:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}
```

What kind of authorization do I need?

Comment: Connection Refused means that Docker can't connect to the website. The error you got on your desktop is completely unrelated.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Hi BMitch,  Thanks for mention the proxy.  I was using vpn.  After I disconnected from vpn, I can run hello-world now.